# Format time with PrettyTime library

Tags: java, android, date, prettytime

Processing news `RSS` feeds and trying to display them with the time elapsed (like 2 min ago, 1 month ago). I'm using [PrettyTime](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime) library for Android.  It works fine for such dates formats

`<pubDate>Thu, 04 Jan 2018 11:00:16 +0000</pubDate>`.

However, if trying to parse, in following format

`<updated>2017-12-30T11:10:44+00:00</updated>`

app is crashing.
That how I parse the dates in the RecyclerView

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime(Locale.ENGLISH);
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    setupImageLoader();

    final News newsItem = newsItems.get(position);
    String imgUrl = newsItem.getNewsImage();
    holder.date_updated.setText(p.format(new Date(newsItem.getUpdated())));
    holder.title.setText(newsItem.getTitle());
```

Any ideas how I can solve this issue?Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Date` class didn't understand given date format. You can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class for parsing date. For your example code will be the next:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("y-MM-dd'T'H:m:ssXXX");
Date date = new Date(format.parse(newsItem.getUpdated()));
```